# How to calculate a value as the VMA of an output section in ld file reversly

Tags: gcc, arm, ld

I am trying to writing a ld file as link script for my cortex m0 board. Now there is a question when I need to lay a output section at the end of SRAM, and I just want the linker can calculate the LMA automatically. The slice of ld file is like:

```
    . = 0x22000 - SIZEOF(.bss_retain);
    .bss_retain . (NOLOAD):
    {
        __bss_retain_start__ =  ALIGN(4);
        ...
```

0x22000 is the end of SRAM. The output map file is like:

```
                0x00021fa0                . = (0x22000 - SIZEOF (.bss_retain))

.bss_retain     0x00022000       0x60
                0x00022000                __bss_retain_start__ = ALIGN (0x4)
```

It seems that the location counter has been assigned with the correct value, while the LMA of .bss_retain is unexpected.

So I want to know how does this works? And if there is any resolution for the question?

Comment: The name `bss_retain` is misleading.  You are putting code here.  `.bss` is traditionally zero based memory (ie, just cleared at boot).

Comment: Actually I haven't put any code into .bss_retain. The section is used to reserve some "shared" data between ROM and application, and the slice ld above is part of the ROM link file.

Comment: Well, just the name 'bss_retain' is not a good label.  'reserved_for_xxxx' or something like that would be better and the name is what makes me thing you are using it for '.bss'.  Ans also, the LMA/VMA doesn't matter then if all you want is to reserve it.  Your question details *NONE* of this.

Answer (score 0):

Using stanza's like this are confusing to `ld`.  They rarely work.

```
. = 0x22000 - SIZEOF(.bss_retain);
.bss_retain . (NOLOAD):
{
```

The issue is that '.' the location has different meaning inside and outside of a section.  To get this to work, I would suggest you create a seperate [memory region](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/MEMORY.html) and put `bss_retain` in that region.  A memory region does not need to be a physical device.  It is ok, to crave up a physical device into separate partitions.  If you needed to place code, then the LMA/VMA would be an issue.  By the way, I think the issue is the VMA, not the LMA (but I think VMA is what you meant).  The 'load address' only matters for initial boot which might copy 'init data' (and code to be relocated in some circumstances).

Comment: You probably can do this with the '.' operation, but a memory region will end up being easier to understand.  If you have some technical limitation against a memory region, please update to say why.

Comment: Sorry, it should be VMA which was unexpected. It's a typo-error. I have to put some useful data into .bss_retain section, and I hope the linker will layout the section to the end of SRAM according to the real size of the section, so I think it's not feasible to create a MEMORY which requires origin as the address.

Answer (score 0):

I have discussed the weird scenario with my teammate, and we have found a solution although we can't figure out exactly why this works:
[image: expected link result]

It seems that we need to re-calcuate SIZEOF(.bss_retain) after the definition of the section when the linker may know exactly the real size it. But it's still confusing why the previous solution doesn't work.

1. If it's invalid to calculate the size before the definition of a section, why the value of location counter ". = 0x22000 - SIZEOF(.bss_retain)" is right, and the linking was successful?
2. If it's valid, why the VMA is the end of SRAM(0x22000)?